# Understanding Prolog Lists

Tags: prolog, list

I am trying to understand Prolog lists, and how values are 'returned' / instantiated at the end of a recursive function.

I am looking at this simple example:

```
val_and_remainder(X,[X|Xs],Xs).
val_and_remainder(X,[Y|Ys],[Y|R]) :-
   val_and_remainder(X,Ys,R).
```

If I call `val_and_remainder(X, [1,2,3], R).` then I will get the following outputs:

```
X = 1, R = [2,3]; 
X = 2, R = [1,3];
X = 3, R = [1,2];
false.
```

But I am confused as to why in the base case (`val_and_remainder(X,[X|Xs],Xs).`) `Xs` has to appear as it does.

If I was to call `val_and_remainder(2, [1,2,3], R).` then it seems to me as though it would run through the program as:

```
% Initial call
val_and_remainder(2, [1,2,3], R).

val_and_remainder(2, [1|[2,3]], [1|R]) :- val_and_remainder(2, [2,3], R).

% Hits base case
val_and_remainder(2, [2|[3]], [3]).
```

If the above run through is correct then how does it get the correct value for `R`? As in the above case the value of R should be `R = [1,3]`.

Comment: Then how would `Xs` unify with `R`? And more importantly, how does `R` get a value for the result?

Comment: @GuyCoder Please see the updated question (basically the question you asked me, I don't understand it).

Comment: The example predicate you gave in the question I would not consider a good candidate for learning about unification and list. A better example would be [append/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3).

Comment: My question is basicly asking you, how does Prolog put a value into the variable `R` to return? It doesn't. The answer is returned in the third position which is `Xs`. When `Xs` is unified with a value, then the third positiong being `Xs` will hold the result. When that is then unified with the calling predicate the third position which is unbound will unify with the value of `Xs`. Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53818723/1243762) might help.

Comment: Do you understand unification? Also do you understand backward-chaining? If not you need to understand those first. If someone were to post those as questions on StackOveflow and you could not answer them with confidence, then you need to study them more.

Comment: @GuyCoder I understand unification and understand your previous question, but what I don't understand is how the result of `R` is correct, because if you look at my run-though of a program call, the value of `Xs` isn't `[1,3]`, which is what it eventually outputs; it is instead `[3]` which unifies to `R` (clearly I am missing something along the way, but I am unsure what that is).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Prolog, you need to think of *predicates* not as *functions* as you would normally in other languages. *Predicates* describe relationships which might include arguments that help define that relationship.

For example, let's take this simple case:

```
same_term(X, X).
```

This is a *predicate* that defines a relationship between two arguments. Through *unification* it is saying that the first and second arguments are the same if they are unified (and that definition is up to us, the writers of the predicate). Thus, `same_term(a, a)` will succeed, `same_term(a, b)` will fail, and `same_term(a, X)` will succeed with `X = a`.

You could also write this in a more explicit form:

```
same_term(X, Y) :-
    X = Y.  % X and Y are the same if they are unified
```

Now let's look at your example, `val_and_remainder/3`. First, what does it mean?

```
val_and_remainder(X, List, Rest)
```

This means that `X` is an element of `List` and `Rest` is a list consisting of all of the rest of the elements (without `X`). (NOTE: You didn't explain this meaning right off, but I'm determining this meaning from the implementation your example.)

Now we can write out to describe the rules. First, a simple base case:

```
val_and_remainder(X,[X|Xs],Xs).
```

This says that:

> `Xs` is the remainder of list `[X|Xs]` without `X`.

This statement should be pretty obvious by the definition of the `[X|Xs]` syntax for a list in Prolog. You need all of these arguments because the third argument `Xs` must unify with the tail (rest) of list `[X|Xs]`, which is then also `Xs` (variables of the same name are, by definition, unified). As before, you could write this out in more detail as:

```
val_and_remainder(X, [H|T], R) :-
    X = H,
    R = T.
```

But the short form is actually more clear.

Now the recursive clause says:

```
val_and_remainder(X, [Y|Ys], [Y|R]) :- 
    val_and_remainder(X, Ys, R).
```

So this means:

> `[Y|R]` is the remainder of list `[Y|Ys]` without `X` **if** `R` is the remainder of list `Ys` without the element `X`.

You need to think about that rule to convince yourself that it is logically true. The `Y` is the same in second and third arguments because they are referring to the same element, so they must unify.

So these two predicate clauses form two rules that cover both cases. The first case is the simple case where `X` is the first element of the list. The second case is a recursive definition for when `X` is not the first element.

When you make a query, such as `val_and_remainder(2, [1,2,3], R).` Prolog looks to see if it can *unify* the term `val_and_remainder(2, [1,2,3], R)` with a fact or the head of one of your predicate clauses. It fails in its attempt to unify with `val_and_remainder(X,[X|Xs],Xs)` because it would need to unify `X` with `2`, which means it would need to unify `[1,2,3]` with `[2|Xs]` which fails since the first element of `[1,2,3]` is 1, but the first element of `[2|Xs]` is 2.

So Prolog moves on and successfully unifies `val_and_remainder(2, [1,2,3], R)` with `val_and_remainder(X,[Y|Ys],[Y|R])` by unifying `X` with 2, `Y` with 1, `Ys` with `[2,3]`, and `R` with `[Y|R]` (NOTE, this is important, the `R` variable in your call is NOT the same as the `R` variable in the predicate definition, so we should name this `R1` to avoid that confusion). We'll name your `R` as `R1` and say that `R1` is unified with `[Y|R]`.

When the body of the second clause is executed, it calls `val_and_remainder(X,Ys,R).` or, in other words, `val_and_remainder(2, [2,3], R)`. This will unify now with the first clause and give you `R = [3]`. When you unwind all of that, you get, `R1 = [Y|[3]]`, and recalling that `Y` was bound to 1, the result is `R1 = [1,3]`.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you! Sorry to bombard you with another question straight away, but is there any chance you could review my other question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54053834/generating-possible-combinations-in-prolog

Answer (score 3):

Stepwise reproduction of Prolog's mechanism often leads to more confusion than it helps. You probably have notions like "returning" meaning something very specific—more appropriate to imperative languages.

Here are different approaches you can always use:

## Ask the most general query

... and let Prolog explain you what the relation is about.

```
?- val_and_remainder(X, Xs, Ys).
   Xs = [X|Ys]
;  Xs = [_A,X|_B], Ys = [_A|_B]
;  Xs = [_A,_B,X|_C], Ys = [_A,_B|_C]
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_C,X|_D], Ys = [_A,_B,_C|_D]
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_D,X|_E], Ys = [_A,_B,_C,_D|_E]
; ... .
```

So `Xs` and `Ys` share a common list prefix, `Xs` has thereafter an `X`, followed by a common rest. This query would continue producing further answers. Sometimes, you want to see all answers, then you have to be more specific. But don't be too specific:

```
?- Xs = [_,_,_,_], val_and_remainder(X, Xs, Ys).
   Xs = [X,_A,_B,_C], Ys = [_A,_B,_C]
;  Xs = [_A,X,_B,_C], Ys = [_A,_B,_C]
;  Xs = [_A,_B,X,_C], Ys = [_A,_B,_C]
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_C,X], Ys = [_A,_B,_C]
;  false.
```

So here we got all possible answers for a four-element list. All of them.

## Stick to ground goals when going through specific inferences

So instead of `val_and_remainder(2, [1,2,3], R).` (which obviously got your head spinning) rather consider `val_and_remainder(2, [1,2,3], [1,3]).` and then
`val_and_remainder(2, [2,3],[3])`. From this side it should be obvious.

## Read Prolog rules right-to-left

See Prolog rules as production rules. Thus, whenever everything holds on the right-hand side of a rule, you can conclude what is on the left. Thus, the `:-` is an early 1970s' representation of a ←

Later on, you may want to ponder more complex questions, too. Like

## Functional dependencies

> Does the first and second argument uniquely determine the last one? Does `X`, `Xs` → `Ys` hold?

Here is a sample query that asks for `Ys` and `Ys2` being different for the same `X` and `Xs`.

```
?- val_and_remainder(X, Xs, Ys), val_and_remainder(X, Xs, Ys2), dif(Ys,Ys2).
   Xs = [X,_A,X|_B], Ys = [_A,X|_B], Ys2 = [X,_A|_B], dif([_A,X|_B],[X,_A|_B])
;  ... .
```

So apparently, there are different values for `Ys` for a given `X` and `Xs`. Here is a concrete instance:

```
?- val_and_remainder(x, [x,a,x], Ys).
   Ys = [a,x]
;  Ys = [x,a]
;  false.
```

There is no classical returning here. It does not return once but twice. It's more of a `yield`.

Yet, there **is** in fact a functional dependency between the arguments! Can you find it? And can you Prolog-wise prove it (as much as Prolog can do a proof, indeed).

Comment: could you please clarify what does it mean "a functional dependency between the arguments does exist"? Does it mean "formulate a query that is guaranteed to always produce just one answer" (variant: no more than one answers)?

Comment: @Will: We have already the relation defined. And now we consider properties of this relation. One is the notion of functional dependency. That notion from relational databases is easily extended to infinite relations.  And that what I am asking for: Which arguments are determining uniquely which other arguments. (As for the proof: a proof for a relation that is non-terminating for the most general query might be non-terminating as well. Well, we have to accept that)

Answer (score 2):

From comment:

> How the result of R is correct, because if you look at my run-though
>   of a program call, the value of Xs isn't [1,3], which is what it
>   eventually outputs; it is instead [3] which unifies to R (clearly I am
>   missing something along the way, but I am unsure what that is).

This is correct:

```
% Initial call
val_and_remainder(2, [1,2,3], R).

val_and_remainder(2, [1|[2,3]], [1|R]) :- val_and_remainder(2, [2,3], R).

% Hits base case
val_and_remainder(2, [2|[3]], [3]).
```

however Prolog is not like other programming languages where you enter with input and exit with output at a return statement. In Prolog you move forward through the predicate statements unifying and continuing with predicates that are true, and upon backtracking also unifying the unbound variables. (That is not technically correct but it is easier to understand for some if you think of it that way.)

You did not take into consideration the the unbound variables that are now bound upon backtracking.

When you hit the base case `Xs` was bound to `[3]`,

but when you backtrack you have look at

```
val_and_remainder(2, [1|[2,3]], [1|R])
```

and in particular `[1|R]` for the third parameter.

Since `Xs` was unified with `R` in the call to the base case, i.e.

```
val_and_remainder(X,[X|Xs],Xs).
```

`R` now has `[3]`.

Now the third parameter position in

```
val_and_remainder(2, [1|[2,3]], [1|R])
```

is `[1|R]` which is `[1|[3]]` which as syntactic sugar is `[1,3]` and not just `[3]`.

Now when the query

```
val_and_remainder(2, [1,2,3], R).
```

was run, the third parameter of the query `R` was unified with the third parameter of the predicate

```
val_and_remainder(X,[Y|Ys],[Y|R])
```

so `R` was unified with `[Y|R]` which unpon backtracking is `[1,3]`
and thus the value bound to the query variable `R` is `[1,3]`

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the name of your predicate. It is a distraction anyway. The non-uniform naming of the variables is a distraction as well. Let's use some neutral, short one-syllable names to focus on the code itself in its clearest form:

```erlang
foo( H, [H | T], T).                          % 1st clause

foo( X, [H | T], [H | R]) :- foo( X, T, R).   % 2nd clause
```

So it's the built-in [`select/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=select/3). *Yay!*..

Now you ask about the query `foo( 2, [1,2,3], R)` and how does `R` gets its value set correctly. The main thing missing from your rundown is the *renaming* of variables when a matching clause is selected. The [*resolution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) of the query goes like this:

```erlang
|-  foo( 2, [1,2,3], R) ? { } 
  %% SELECT -- 1st clause, with rename
  |-  ?  { foo( H1, [H1|T1], T1) = foo( 2, [1,2,3], R) }
         **FAIL** (2 = 1)
         **BACKTRACK to the last SELECT**
  %% SELECT -- 2nd clause, with rename
  |-  foo( X1, T1, R1) ?
         { foo( X1, [H1|T1], [H1|R1]) = foo( 2, [1,2,3], R) }
         **OK**
    %% REWRITE
    |-  foo( X1, T1, R1) ?
          { X1=2, [H1|T1]=[1,2,3], [H1|R1]=R }
    %% REWRITE
    |-  foo( 2, [2,3], R1) ?  { R=[1|R1] } 
      %% SELECT -- 1st clause, with rename
      |-  ? { foo( H2, [H2|T2], T2) = foo( 2, [2,3], R1), R=[1|R1] }
             ** OK ** 
        %% REWRITE
        |-  ? { H2=2, T2=[3], T2=R1, R=[1|R1] }
        %% REWRITE
        |-  ? { R=[1,3] }
        %% DONE
```

The goals between `|-` and `?` are the *resolvent*, the equations inside `{ }` are the *substitution*. The knowledge base (KB) is implicitly to the left of `|-` in its entirety.

On each step, the left-most goal in the resolvent is chosen, a clause with the matching head is chosen among the ones in the KB <sup>*(while **renaming** all of the clause's variables in the consistent manner, such that no variable in the resolvent is used by the renamed clause, so there's no accidental variable capture)*</sup>, and the chosen goal is replaced in the resolvent with that clause's body, while the successful unification is added into the substitution. When the resolvent is empty, the query has been proven and what we see is the one successful *and*-branch in the whole [*and-or* tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And%E2%80%93or_tree#Relationship_with_logic_programming).

---

This is how a machine could be doing it.  The "rewrite" steps are introduced here for ease of human comprehension.

So we can see here that the first successful clause selection results in the equation

```erlang
     R = [1 | R1     ]
```

, and the second, --

```erlang
              R1 = [3]
```

, which together entail

```erlang
     R = [1,        3]
```

This gradual top-down instantiation / fleshing-out of lists is a very characteristic Prolog's way of doing things.

---

In response to the bounty challenge, regarding functional dependency in the relation `foo/3` (i.e. `select/3`): in `foo(A,B,C)`, any two ground values for `B` and `C` uniquely determine the value of `A` (or its absence):

```erlang
2 ?- foo( A, [0,1,2,1,3], [0,2,1,3]).
A = 1 ;
false.

3 ?- foo( A, [0,1,2,1,3], [0,1,2,3]).
A = 1 ;
false.

4 ?- foo( A, [0,1,2,1,3], [0,1,2,4]).
false.

f ?- foo( A, [0,1,1], [0,1]).
A = 1 ;
A = 1 ;
false.
```

Attempt to disprove it by a counterargument:

```erlang
10 ?- dif(A1,A2), foo(A1,B,C), foo(A2,B,C).
Action (h for help) ? abort
% Execution Aborted
```

Prolog fails to find a counterargument.

Tying to see more closely what's going on, with iterative deepening:

```erlang
28 ?- length(BB,NN), foo(AA,BB,CC), XX=[AA,BB,CC], numbervars(XX), 
      writeln(XX), (NN>3, !, fail).
[A,[A],[]]
[A,[A,B],[B]]
[A,[B,A],[B]]
[A,[A,B,C],[B,C]]
[A,[B,A,C],[B,C]]
[A,[B,C,A],[B,C]]
[A,[A,B,C,D],[B,C,D]]
false.

29 ?- length(BB,NN), foo(AA,BB,CC), foo(AA2,BB,CC), 
      XX=[AA,AA2,BB,CC],  numbervars(XX), writeln(XX), (NN>3, !, fail).
[A,A,[A],[]]
[A,A,[A,B],[B]]
[A,A,[A,A],[A]]
[A,A,[A,A],[A]]
[A,A,[B,A],[B]]
[A,A,[A,B,C],[B,C]]
[A,A,[A,A,B],[A,B]]
[A,A,[A,A,A],[A,A]]
[A,A,[A,A,B],[A,B]]
[A,A,[B,A,C],[B,C]]
[A,A,[B,A,A],[B,A]]
[A,A,[A,A,A],[A,A]]
[A,A,[B,A,A],[B,A]]
[A,A,[B,C,A],[B,C]]
[A,A,[A,B,C,D],[B,C,D]]
false.
```

`AA` and `AA2` are always instantiated to the same variable.

There's nothing special about the number 3, so it is safe to conjecture by  generalization that it will always be so, for any length tried.

---

Another attempt at Prolog-wise proof:

```erlang
ground_list(LEN,L):-
  findall(N, between(1,LEN,N), NS), 
  member(N,NS),
  length(L,N), 
  maplist( \A^member(A,NS), L).

bcs(N, BCS):- 
  bagof(B-C, A^(ground_list(N,B),ground_list(N,C),foo(A,B,C)), BCS).

as(N, AS):- 
  bagof(A, B^C^(ground_list(N,B),ground_list(N,C),foo(A,B,C)), AS).

proof(N):-
  as(N,AS), bcs(N,BCS), 
  length(AS,N1), length(BCS, N2), N1 =:= N2.
```

This compares the number of successful `B-C` combinations overall with the number of `A`s they produce. Equality means one-to-one correspondence.

And so we have,

```erlang
2 ?- proof(2).
true.

3 ?- proof(3).
true.

4 ?- proof(4).
true.

5 ?- proof(5).
true.
```

And so for any `N` it holds. Getting slower and slower. A general, unlimited query is trivial to write, but the slowdown seems exponential.

Comment: Not sure why you produce a further definition with another name. The question was about the OP's definition.

Comment: You give concrete examples, you could do better than proof by (single, ground) example

Comment: Your program is able to produce a counterexample, should there be one! (After an unspecified period, indeed).  But you need to make the argument why it is able to do so! Looking at some examples does not provide this kind of certainty.

Comment: `numbervars` is unsafe! Think of `freeze(X, X = 1), numbervars(X,0,_)` - SWI produces an error which is kind-of nice. Even better is to use a better toplevel

Comment: thanks, will work on it some more.... (numbervars are only used for showing the results in a readable fashion). if you mean SICStus, it's non-free, though indeed relatively cheap for personal use. if not, which would you recommend?

Comment: To me, SICStus is the only choice for the moment. But SWI might improve, too. You would have to put an effort there, though

Comment: @false thank you very much for the bounty. :) I suspect you wanted a bit more than that, too. :) I don't exactly understand how to make `bagof` and friends work here  when there are uninstantiated vars in terms, so had to do extensive testing instead. maybe should have used 2N range for the second list to really be exhaustive...

Comment: How can be your answer useful to further readers? First of all, this name-switching. Why do you do this at all. It's this little extra effort that causes people to stop reading...

Comment: as I said in the answer, I couldn't understand what was meant by "val_and_remainder". so to not get distracted, I gave it a neutral name, to focus on code only. same with the variables names. For me, it was *saving* the effort, and to have to repeat the name was harder, for me. if it's meaningless, better if it's short. it's a personal comprehension / perception thing. as they say, "YMMV."